# SQL copy and replace records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am quite new to SQL and having troubles with my code. I have been trying to copy a line in a table and replacing part of the record. However, I keep getting the error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

The following code gives the error:

```
  insert into mi_structure
  select replace parent_mi_id, (child_mi_id,'GR','GR_V') child_mi_id, startdate, enddate, mutnr
  from mi_structure
  where parent_mi_id like 'MIPFV%29'
    and sysdate between startdate and enddate;
```

The table mi_structure with the following code looks like this

```
  select *
  from mi_structure
  where parent_mi_id like 'MIPFV%29'
    and sysdate between startdate and enddate;


PARENT_MI_ID   ||   CHILD_MI_ID       ||   STARTDATE   ||   ENDDATE   || MUTNR
MIPFV_POOL 29  ||   CSLLXXXX.USD.GR   ||   42917       ||   36526     ||   11
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(child_mi_id,'GR','GR_V') ` written like a function but not. probably this causes the error.

Comment: are you trying to use replace function ?  its used like this 
REPLACE('Atestword', 'word', 'Phrase'); =AtestPhrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try this

```
  insert into mi_structure
  select parent_mi_id, replace (child_mi_id,'GR','GR_V') child_mi_id, startdate, enddate, mutnr from mi_structure
  where parent_mi_id like 'MIPFV%29'
  and sysdate between startdate and enddate;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. This gives the updated line as I expect. Does this also add the record to the table?

Comment: it is the only select part, you also should write insert part. I also added insert part

Comment: could you write all necessary columns to insert  like `insert into mi_structure(col1, col2, ....)` instead of `insert into mi_structure`

Comment: I found the problem, had to do with the child_mi_id being absent in another table. Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

> select replace parent_mi_id, (child_mi_id,'GR','GR_V') child_mi_id,
>   startdate, enddate, mutnr from mi_structure

it seems you are using replace function wrong it should be like the below

```
insert into mi_structure (parent_mi_id_col,child_mi_id_col,startdate_col,enddate,mutnr) 
  select parent_mi_id, replace(child_mi_id,'GR','GR_V') child_mi_id, startdate, enddate, mutnr
  from mi_structure
      where parent_mi_id like 'MIPFV%29'
      and sysdate between startdate and enddate;
```

btw I recommand you add the columns in the insert as above.

Comment: But then the headers are not in the right order. Isn't that a problem? And does this add the line to the table?

Comment: if there are inserte .then yes its a problem , ill add the insert part. btw  I recommand you add the columns in the insert as in my example